# Redirect 12,000 pages from SPIP to Wordpress

Tags: redirect, wordpress

I'd like to switch from SPIP to Wordpress and redirect all SPIP's URLs to Wordpress ones.

The format for an SPIP URL is: `example.com/spip.php?article{ID}`, for example: `example.com/spip.php?article123`

The format for a Wordpress URL is: `example.com/?p={ID}`, for example: `example.com/?p=123`

If I transfer all data to Wordpress under the same IDs it would mean `example.com/spip.php?article123` is exactly `example.com/?p=123`

My question is: how so I actually do this? I've searched many forums and how just found ways to transfer a page with specific pattern (without question mark) to a new pattern, with question mark.

Answer (score 3):

You have not specified the web server - which is important.  I am assuming you are using Apache as it is probably the most common server for this kind of hosting.

To do this you need to add a rewriteRule in your apache config (in a Directory container) or .htaccess file.  Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^article(.*)$
RewriteRule ^spip.php?$ /index.php?p=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

To switch from SPIP to WordPress and redirect automatically the URLs, you can use the plugin [FG SPIP to WordPress](http://www.fredericgilles.net/fg-spip-to-wordpress/).